# Save columns from Pandas dataframe to csv, without reading the csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I was wondering if there is a method to store ones columns from a dataframe to an already existing csv file without reading the entire file first?

I am working with a very large dataset, where I read 2-5 columns of the dataset, use them for calculating a new variable(column) and I want to store this variable to the entire dataset. My memory can not load the entire dataset at once and therefore I am looking for a way to store the new columns to the entire dataset without loading all of it.

I have tried using chunking with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(Path, chunksize = 10000000)
```

But then I am faced with the Error "TypeError: 'TextFileReader' object is not subscriptable" When trying to process the data.

The data is also grouped by two variables and therefore chunking is not preferred when doing these calculations.

Comment: Have you tried loading only the columns you need with `pd.read_csv` parameter `usecols`? If that still throws a memory error, you may want to use `dask` or write your data to an SQL data base and write a query to do your aggregates afterwards. Alternatively, you could create separate sort your data into separate CSVs that you deal with separately.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I am only loading the columns I need using 'usecols'. However, I can not figure out how to save the newly generated columns to the full dataframe.

Comment: I don't think you can't append them horizontally; you can append rows, but not columns. If you really want them in one file, consider creating an output file where the row indices are perfectly aligned. Then in chunks, `pd.concat([original, columns_to_add], axis=1)` and save with append.

Comment: I need to feed the dataset to a neural network, so it is convenient to have all the variables in the same dataset. Thank you for the reply though.